# Best method to upload data to multiple documents in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am currently working on an iOS App that uses Cloud Firestore from Firebase.

I was wondering: what is the best way (cost, efficiency and security-wise) to upload some data to multiple Firestore documents simultaneously (or almost simultaneously)?

* The data I have to upload consists of the following: there are two users (User A is the user currently using the app, User B is the one whose profile is currently being seen by User A). If User A saves User B's profile, I must upload User B's UID to User A's Firestore Document. Then, I have to increase a counter in User A's Firestore Document. Finally, I must add User A's UID to User B's Firestore Document. - Note that with Firestore Document I mean either a document Field or a document Subcollection.

The choices are:

- **Upload everything from the client**: seems the best method, cost-wise: it doesn't require extra Cloud Functions usage. I would create a Batch Operation and upload all the data from there*. The downside is that the client must be able to access multiple unrelated collections and documents.
- **Update one document from the client, then update everything else from Cloud Functions**: this method is the best one efficiency and security-wise; the client only uploads data to the user's document*, without accessing unrelated collections and documents. Also, the client only has to upload a fraction of the data that it had to upload in the previous method, saving bandwidth and cellular data / WiFi usage. The downside is that the usage of Cloud Functions would increase, eventually resulting in more costs.
- **Update one document from the client, update the counter* from the client and then update everything else form Cloud Functions**: this method is somewhat a hybrid between the first two, as I think that updating the counter from the client is more secure (Cloud Functions' `.onWrite` trigger may happen twice or more, increasing the counter multiple times?).

My first thought was to go with method 2, as it's far more secured and efficient, but I would like to have someone else's advice too, before "wasting" too much time coding something wrong.

I hope this isn't any kind of duplicate, as I couldn't find anything that answered my question with enough specificity.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow the **third approach**: updating from the client the current user collections (the *saved_profiles* collection and the *counter* field), which are private and only accessible by this user (configure [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)) and updating the other user's collection (*users_who_saved_my_profile*) with a triggered Cloud Function. As these operations are not controlled by security rules, they can access any part of the database. This way no unnecessary permissions are granted to any user.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your advice.